# Can you use a regression equation to predict parameters in both directions?

Tags: regression, expected-value

I am critiquing a statistics question that will be given to students. It has a formula, where we can obtain the Expected Adult Height from birth length, (with the implied understanding, I believe, that a simple regression equation E(height) = a + bx, where x = birth length, was used).  Now this is fine to be interpolating the expected adult height. But is it technically correct to go the other direction, and predict a birth length from a current adult height using the same formula?

I have some doubts, because the methods to develop such a model uses matrices, which aren't necessarily commutative.  Therefore, I have a feeling that the distributions of adult heights are quite different to the distributions of birth length, and therefore a model going the other way may be quite different, because it starts in different places. But will the Expected values be effectively equal? If my doubts are true, is there a simple statement to justify my doubts, such as "The models are not commutative" or "expected values imply directionality in the modelling"?

Answer (score 3):

If
$$
{\rm Height} = \hat{a} + \hat{b}*{\rm Length} 
$$
is the estimated equation in regression of Height onto Length, then it will not be suitable for predicting Length out of Height. It will not be suitable for predictions "in the opposite direction". The reason is *regression to the mean*. If you calculate the optimal equation for regressing Length onto Height,
$$
{\rm Length} = \hat{c} + \hat{d}*{\rm Height},
$$
it will not be algebraically equivalent to the first equation. In other words,
$$
\hat{c}\neq -\frac{\hat{a}}{\hat{b}},
$$
$$
\hat{d}\neq\frac{1}{\hat{b}},
$$
generally speaking. The issue is well explained in

*Freedman, D., Pisani, R., & Purves, R. (2007). Statistics.*

among other resources. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal variables with correlation $\rho \in (-1,1)$. Then the $(X_i,Y_i)$ data points form a perfectly elliptic cloud. The two regression lines are symmetric relative to the $y = x$ line and cross it an angle.